# How to make the read-only port 10255 only available in the vpc in Google Cloud with GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I noticed I have the read only port 10255 opened to the wide web. We want to make it available only from inside the VPC, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56920981/2104697) is suggesting. I'm not sure how to specify such rule. I've tried something like that:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "testcloseport" --action=DENY --rules tcp:10255  --source-tags=public --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --description="Close port 10255 from outside the vpc"
```

I unfortunately got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/myproject-prod/global/networks/default' was not found
```

I tried to set the region and zone like this:

```
gcloud config set compute/region us-east1
gcloud config set compute/zone us-east1-d
```

I still got the error. I simply want to close this port for the outside of the VPC. Is there a way I can change the `firewall-rules create` command so it works?

Comment: The answer, in which you're basing your question, implies that you already have or create a VPC network, did you already create one? Quoting **“If you are using VPC you can add firewall rules to port (10255) to allow incoming traffic only from the resources on VPC.”**

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error:

> The resource 'projects/myproject-prod/global/networks/default' was not
> found

is because the `gcloud` command you are attempting to run defaults to the VPC named "default" which is the one that comes by default.

In order to create the firewall rule to a custom network (VPC) you have to pass the parameter `--network` for example (replace the <MY_VPC_NAME>):

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules create testcloseport --network <MY_VPC_NAME> --action=DENY --rules tcp:10255  --source-tags=public --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --description="Close port 10255 from outside the vpc"
```

One more thing, with the rule above you will deny any IP source on port 10255 so you might need a second rule with a higher priority allowing port `10255` only to the private subnet you would like to allow that connection through.